# Using Jquery Filter as a way to filter links on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a list of links on a page and a set of checkboxes that should filter the links so that only the ones that have the specific criteria will be active. My rudimentary attempt to do this involves creating an array of all the filter options that are active and running a .filter(Array) to make those active and a .not(Array) to disable the other links.

The problem is that if more than one filter options is selected any link that matches either filter option will be active. When in reality what i want is only the links that match ALL the filter options to be active.

Here is my stripped down version in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bardsworth/S2JCQ/2/)

```
var filterAll = ["filter-F_0", "filter-F_1", "filter-F_2", "filter-F_3", "filter-F_4", "filter-P_0", "filter-P_1", "filter-P_2", "filter-P_3", ]
var filterActive = [];

function filterApps(){
if(filterActive.length == 0)
{
    filterReset();
    return;
}

var arrActive = $.map(filterActive, function (val) {
                                                        return '[' + val + ']'
                                                    }).join(",")

addToLog("arr = " + arrActive);

$(".appLink").filter(arrActive).css(activeAppCSS).addClass("active").removeClass("disable");


$(".appLink").not(arrActive).css(disabledAPPCSS).addClass("disable").removeClass("active");}
```

Comment: _"instead of this and this and this are the criterias and only those that meet those criteria shoudl be active. "_ Can you be more specific please?

Comment: currently if you choose more than one filter option anything that matches either of the filter options will be active. When in reality what i want is only the links that match both filter options to be active. *make more sense*?

Comment: i edited my post to be a bit clearer. (i hope)

Answer (score 0):

You have complicated many things here, using attribute's name for filtering the elements is a terrible idea (*sorry*), you could use [`data-*`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) attributes that store the filtering criteria in an array. If I have understood the question correctly something like the following should work, this solution reads the attributes' name using `attributes` property, it should be noted that it's not the most efficient way of doing the task and as Array object's `.filter()` method is used it doesn't work in older browsers that don't support ES5, for supporting those browsers you can use a [shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).

```
var $links = $('.appLink');
var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    // Creating an array of values
    var checked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function () {
        return this.value.toLowerCase();
    }).get();

    // Filtering the .appLink elements by reading the attributes
    // and comparing the filtered array's length with the checked one 
    $links.removeClass('matched').filter(function () {
       return [].slice.call(this.attributes).filter(function (a) {
            return a.name.indexOf('filter') === 0;
        }).filter(function(f) {
            return $.inArray(f.name.replace('filter-', ''), checked) > -1;
        }).length === checked.length;
    }).addClass('matched');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/85tTp/

In case that you want to use `data-*` properties, you can define an attribute like `data-filter='["f1", "f2", ""]'` for the elements and use jQuery `.data()` method for reading them:

```
$links.removeClass('matched').filter(function () {
   return $(this).data('filter').filter(function(f) {
        return $.inArray(f, checked) > -1;
    }).length === checked.length;
}).addClass('matched');
```